# Failed to construct 'AudioWorkletNode'

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

I was working on an application that used the WEB AUDIO API. And things were going well, untill I got this error:

DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioWorkletNode': AudioWorkletNode cannot be created: AudioWorklet does not have a valid AudioWorkletGlobalScope. Load a script via audioWorklet.addModule() first.

I have searched the internet for this, and I couldn't figure it out.

I will show you all relevant code.

```
    record(){
        const toast = useToast();

        if(!navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        }
        if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then((stream) => {
                this.success(stream);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.error(e);
            })
        } else {
             toast.error('getUserMedia is not supported in this browser');
        }
    },

    success(e){
        let audioContext = window.AudioContext;
        let context = new audioContext();
        context.audioWorklet.addModule('../../../public/js/processor.js');
        console.log(context);
        let audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(context, 'worklet-processor');
    }
```

and my processor (it is empty I know)

```
class WorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    process(){
        return true;
    }
}
registerProcessor('worklet-processor', WorkletProcessor);
```

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the promise returned by `addModule()` is not waited for. Turning your `success()` function into an `async` function and using `await` to wait for the promise to resolve should solve the problem.

```
success async (e) {
    let context = new AudioContext();
    await context.audioWorklet.addModule('../../../public/js/processor.js');
    let audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(context, 'worklet-processor');
}
```